# jasmine test is not working for angulardirective?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

trying to test my directive with jasmine but is not failing where it should because of the wrong date(.demo):

```
describe("Unit: Testing Directives - ", function() {
  var $compile, $rootScope;
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  describe("Date Validation Directive - ", function(){
    it('should show an date as valid', function(){
      $rootScope.demo = '10/01/881';
      var templateHTML = angular.element('<input class="blah" type="tel" ng-model="demo" my-date />');
      var element = $compile(templateHTML)($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$digest();
      expect(element.hasClass('ng-valid')).toBe(true);
      expect(element.hasClass('ng-invalid')).toBe(false);

    });
  });
});
```

this is what my directive looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive("myDate", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A", //only activate on element attribute
    require: "ngModel", //get hold of NgModelController
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var date_regexp = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
            if (date_regexp.test(viewValue)) {
                // it is valid
                ctrl.$setValidity("myDate", true);
                return viewValue;
            } else {
                // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
                ctrl.$setValidity("myDate", false);
                return undefined;
            }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

how can I get it working?
plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/GYBvynRqdTTqXxnk7thN?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the programmatic assignment of the model value. `$parsers` run when he value is modified through DOM. When you change the model value programatically it is `$formatters` that run. So in your directive if you change [`$parsers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) to [`$formatters`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) it will fail the test as you expected.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLX0Em?p=preview)**

However you may need both of them in your directive and your real testing should be to test the logic inside the parsers/formatters, not how it is run (It has already been tested by angular) or how the classes are added by angular. If your validations are exposed through say a validator service, or even your directive's controller which provides the validation that would be a good target to test.